# Local static const variables that may need to refer to different variables

Tags: c++

I have a function that has a variable called `static const int initial_var = some_var` so that on subsequent runs to the function, `initial_var` is guaranteed to not change. The issue is however the function may be called for different `some_var`s and because `initial_var` is used in calculations, this can screw things up.

`func()` is meant to operate on DIFFERENT variables, all named `some_var`. Their state needs to be remembered so I use a static const variable, but that will only remember the state for ONE variable.

```
void func()
{
   static const int initial_var = some_var;
   some_var = initial_var; // This is the part where things may screw up if some_var
                           // is a different variable
}
```

What's an elegant way to fix this?

Comment: Please try again to explain the problem, your description does not make any sense (to me, anyway)

Comment: It would be good to include a complete program that shows the problem (and explain what output you expected)

Comment: If you want a function to do different things, it sounds like you actually need different *functions*. Or, since you're programming in C++, abstract it out into classes, and have instances of that class with different data?

Comment: @Joachim In reality, some_var IS an object with different data, but I have ONE function that operates on instances of that class.

Comment: If `some_var` is an object why not store it as its type in an array?

Comment: Sounds like a member function then...

Comment: Must be a member function: no arguments are passed. How should the function guess which of the many some_var to use !?

Answer (score 0):

You say you need "Their state needs to be remembered" so you can just put them in an array.

```
int array[10]; // 10 elements.
int count = 0;

void storeVariable(int temp)
{
    array[count] = temp;
    count++;

    // Reset if full.
    if(count >= 10)
       count = 0; 
}
```

That seems fairly simple enough.